# Odoo pivot report false values are translated to "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, python, pivot, report, odoo

In Odoo (v. 10) pivot report values `false` appear as "Undefined" while values `true` appear as "true".

I found in odoo source the [line `if (value === false) return _t("Undefined");`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/2d12ae3202ed93a12e1f8ff59bf64e82c0c98871/addons/web/static/src/js/views/pivot_view.js#L509)

What might be the logic behind that (to make "false" look "Undefined") while leaving "true" as "true"?

Answer (score 2):

Because 'false' values can come from different type of data : boolean, but also when a string is empty, or also when a number is 0.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. One thing that comes to my mind is convert 'true', 'false' to strings and treat them as strings. What is common way of treating false that come in Odoo reports? Because odoo javascript code `if (value **===** false)` (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/2d12ae3202ed93a12e1f8ff59bf64e82c0c98871/addons/web/static/src/js/views/pivot_view.js#L509) compares with **regard to the type**. I don't get why boolean values are treated differently in Odoo.

Comment: Boolean values are treated in Odoo like they are treated in Python. There is no typing of variable in Python, so you can't compare with *regard to type*.